# Selecting Feature Class from drop down list of all Feature Classes in Geodatabase In ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

Is there a feature of ModelBuilder that allows a user to select a feature class based on a list of all feature classes in a geodatabase, ie upon opening the tool, the user will select the geodatabase and then will see a list of all feature classes available to run the tool on.

Iterate doesn't seem to work, because I can't find a way to input the results into the a list in the parameters. Multivalue doesn't work either if I have to manually populate the list.

Comment: Have you tried the Select Data tool?  It allows you to select a geodatabase and have a drop down of the feature classes found within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Baltok in the comments, you can use the select data tool.

Add this to the beginning of your model.

[image]

To make the child data element a parameter, right click on 'Select Data' and say make variable from parameter and select child data element.  Then make the child data element a model parameter.

[image]